# Is it possible to print arguments passed to a swift functions as variableName: variableValue?

Tags: ios, swift, logging, arguments

I want to add logging to my current iOS application written in Swift. I would like to print the function name followed by a list of args passed to it as `variableName: variableValue`. I know we can get the function name using `#function`. But is it possible to access arguments of a function as an array? If I can't convert the variable name to string then at least I would like to print the list of arguments.

#### Edit:

I need to do this for 100s of functions so *I CAN'T* edit the way arguments are passed in or the return type of my functions!!!

E.g. Ideally a `makeArgsString` helper function like this:

```
func getUsernameFromEmail(email: String) -> String? { 

print("\(#function) called with: \(makeArgsString(arguments: args))",)

...

}


func makeArgsString(arguments: [Any]) -> {
  let argsString = ""
  for argument in arguments {
    argsString += "\(argument.name) - \(argument)" 
    //OR
    argsString += "\(argument) " 
  }
}
```

Comment: I know I've seen this kind of thing in logging libraries before, so it must exist, but I'm trying to find an example and am not having much luck. Still looking.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you can tell me the logging library's name then I can also try to find later. :)

Comment: I can't find anything useful. Kind of surprising. Maybe some combination of parsing #function and applying KeyPath would be useful, but a bit messy. Good luck with this problem.

Comment: That sucks! :/ But you have seen this in libraries?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible without manually typing out the arguments into one of the existing loggers or writing your own.  Ive seen libraries that help with debug logging, but not one that is able to automatically log the function arguments.  Here is an example of a [logger](https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger)

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective-c_runtime

[Get Method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418887-class_getclassmethod)

[Method Name](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418758-method_getname)

[# of Arguments](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418758-method_getname)

[Return Type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418591-method_getreturntype)

[Argument Type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418607-method_getargumenttype)

So you can iterate through each argument, and at least get the TYPE, maybe not the specific name...

```
class Logger: NSObject {

    static let shared = Logger(name: "MyLogger")

    let name = ""

    private init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    public func printFuncData(function:Selector) {
        /*    method    */
        let method = class_getClassMethod(yourClass.self, function)

        /*    name    */
        let name = function.StringLiteralType

        /*    arguments    */
        //Allocate space for the methods
        let maxChars = 256
        let ctype = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: maxChars)

        //We do this because the first 2 arguments should NOT be our custom methods
        let numArguments = method_getNumberOfArguments(method) - 2

        //We do this because the first 2 arguments should NOT be our custom methods
        for j in 2 ..< Int(numberOfArguments) + 2 {
            method_getArgumentType(method, UInt32(j), ctype, maxChars)
            print("argumentType: \(String(cString: ctype))")
        }
    }
}
```

In this manner, it is impossible to obtain WHAT values you inserted into the function, so you will have to MANUALLY include the VALUES of what you inserted... a minor bit of overhead for your problem.

```
    public func printFuncData(class:AnyClass, function:Selector, values:Any...) {
        /*    method    */
        let method = class_getClassMethod(yourClass.self, function)
        
         /*    name    */
        let name = function.StringLiteralType

        /*    arguments    */
        //Allocate space for the methods
        let maxChars = 256
        let ctype = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: maxChars)

        //We do this because the first 2 arguments should NOT be our custom methods
        let numArguments = method_getNumberOfArguments(method) - 2

        //We do this because the first 2 arguments should NOT be our custom methods
        //ADDITIONALLY, we assume that the # of variadic parameters are EQUAL to the # of method arguments... I don't check for it here.
        for j in 2 ..< Int(numberOfArguments) + 2 {
            method_getArgumentType(method, UInt32(j), ctype, maxChars)
            print("argumentType: \(String(cString: ctype)) -- Value: values[j]") //<-- Added Values
        }
    }
```

**Example:**

```
class myClass {
    func myFunc(arg1: String, arg2: String, arg3: Int) {
        Logger.shared.printFuncData(class: myClass.self, function: myFunc, values: arg1, arg2, arg3)
    }
}
```

In the case above, the only little but you would have to manually enter is the argument values, `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3`.

So, a little bit of overhead, but hopefully this will get you in the right direction.

Note: I did type this on SO and am currently unable to test everything, i.e. small syntax issues, but the premise should be there

Comment: Yeah but again I have to pass arg1, arg2, arg3 here. I really which there was a `args` variable like c does in swift.

Comment: True but you can take them in as a variadic parameter and get their type since we can see how many there are. This does make it a lot easier, compared to the alternative. Like I said, a lil overhead. Additionally, you can `locals()` in python - I have seen libraries in Swift to execute python code. Maybe try that?